# Logging into Twitter OAuth using username and password (Python)

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

So, what I am trying to do is logging in to my Twitter account using my Twitter credentials. I know that is possible, I just don't know how to do it :/. I think that the method is similar independent of the programing language, but I am using Python. This is my code to login using the access tokens and consumer keys:

```
from twitter import *

token = "*******"
token_key = "******"
con_secret = "*******"
con_secret_key = "*******"

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(token, token_key, con_secret, con_secret_key))

t.statuses.home_timeline()
t.statuses.update(status="Hello World!")
```

But I want to do it using something like this:

```
from twitter import *

username = "username"
password = "password"

(...)

t.statuses.update(status="Hello World!")
```

and then it would login.
How can I do that? If you don't know how to do it in Python, tell me in another language, because I guess it won't change much.

Comment: Please go through this site it's says all api used for twitter https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries.

Comment: @RahulKP yes, but that doesn't tell how to log in with username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way was using twitter.auth.UserPassAuth however it is deprecated.
It returns

```
{'errors': [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]}
```

Comment: well, definitely didn't expect to get an answer to a question I asked almost 7 years ago lol, I think 13yo me would be thankful! Thanks anyway :)